# word count engine, output using square brackets and order incorrect

Tags: python, dictionary

I came across that question online:

> Word Count Engine
>
> Implement a document scanning function wordCountEngine, which receives
>   a string document and returns a list of all unique words in it and
>   their number of occurrences, **sorted by the number of occurrences in
>   a descending order. If two or more words have the same count, they
>   should be sorted according to their order in the original sentence.**
>   Assume that all letters are in english alphabet. You function should
>   be case-insensitive, so for instance, the words “Perfect” and
>   “perfect” should be considered the same word.
>
> **The engine should strip out punctuation (even in the middle of a word) and use whitespaces to separate words.**
>
> Analyze the time and space complexities of your solution. Try to
>   optimize for time while keeping a polynomial space complexity.

So I attempted a solutions and it works fine, just 2 issues:

1. when I sort the words descending order, if 2 words have the same number I should sort based on their appearance , I can't seem to do that part
2. the expected out is enclosed between `[]` while mine is enclosed between `()`

my code is as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import operator

def word_count_engine(document):
  #c=collections.Counter(document.split())

  myDict=defaultdict(str) #will use a dict
  document=document.lower()
  document+=" " #just to count the last word so I add a space at the end
  word=""


  for i in range(len(document)):
    if document[i].islower(): #as long as its a normal char append it to word string
      word+=document[i]
    elif document[i].isspace(): #if its a space it means its the end of word
      if word in myDict.keys(): #if its already in dict inc counter
        myDict[word]+=1
      else:
        myDict[word]=1 #if not in dict add it and make count =1
      word="" #clear array
  sorted_x = sorted(myDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)


  print('myDict is ', myDict)     
  print('sorted ', sorted_x)    

  return sorted_x
```

> **Input:**  "Practice makes perfect, you'll get perfecT by practice. just practice! just just just!!"
>
> **Expected:** [["just","4"],["practice","3"],["perfect","2"],["makes","1"],["youll","1"],["get","1"],["by","1"]]
>
> **Actual:**  [('just', 4), ('practice', 3), ('perfect', 2), ('get', 1), ('makes', 1), ('youll', 1), ('by', 1)]

Any ideas how can I fix those 2 issues? the order and the `()` to be `[]`

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: python 3...im using it on the online platform pramp

Comment: I checked, and pramp.com only has Python 2.7, not Python 3.x. You can easily test it: `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` outputs `sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`. (and *ouch*, that's really, really outdated! 2.7.6 is nearly 5 years old, and so a large number of security fixes are sorely missing).

Comment: As of today, Python on Pramp is still 2.7.6!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not tracking word order in the original document, information you need to be able to sort the output correctly. You are also just using the standard `(key, value)` tuples returned by `dict.items()`. You need to return *lists*, and apparently the counts need to be strings too.

In Python versions < 3.6, you'd have to record the order that words appeared in for the first time. Use a `defaultdict()` with a [`itertools.count()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to record a 'first appearance' order number for that:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

word_order = defaultdict(count().__next__)
```

For any word you try to look up in that dictionary, the `__next__` method of a single `count()` instance is called only if the word was not yet accessed before, resulting in a clean ordering number for each:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import count
>>> word_order = defaultdict(count().__next__)
>>> word_order["foo"]
0
>>> word_order["bar"]
1
>>> word_order["foo"]
0
>>> word_order["spam"]
2
>>> word_order
defaultdict(<method-wrapper '__next__' of itertools.count object at 0x109664680>, {'foo': 0, 'bar': 1, 'spam': 2})
```

You can use this information to track word order, and then later on use this information when sorting.

I'll explain below why this probably should be used in Python 3.6 and newer too, as the strict reading of the Python documentation tells us using a `Counter()` object instead might not always work.

To extract *just* words from the input, you'd be much better of with a regular expression to remove everything that's a word or spaces. The `\w` pattern matches *word characters*, which are letters, digits and underscores, and not punctuation.  For most of these kinds of problems, that is plenty. `\s` matches anything that's whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines). Because we want to keep words and spaces, you can use the *inverse* to remove everything else. You can get the inverse by combining the two classes in a new class with `[...]`, and then adding in `^` at the start to match anything that's not part of those two groups. Lowercase the document, and remove the things we want to get rid of:

```
cleaned = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]+", "", document.lower())
```

All that is left to do to get the cleaned words, is to call `cleaned.split()`, producing a list of words without punctuation or other diacritical marks.

You can then use another `defaultdict()` to keep count of your words. You could also use a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), but we are replacing just about everything it can do well with custom code anyway. I'd just integrate the `word_count` results into the key here:

```
counts = defaultdict(int)
cleaned = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]+", "", document.lower())
for word in cleaned.split():
    counts[(word, word_order[word])] += 1
```

The items of the `counts` dictionary give you `(word, index), count`, so you can sort on that information:

```
# each sort item is a ((word, index), count) tuple, sort by descending counts
# and then by ascending index.
ordered = sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda kv: (-kv[1], kv[0][1]))
```

The above sorts on a composite key, `(-count, index)`. By negating the count you sort in descending order (`-10` would sort before `-3`, so a word that appeared 10 times is sorted before words with a lower count), but the second value, the index is used when two words have the same frequency and is used in ascending order.

Now all that remains is the extraction of the words and the counts from this structure, turning counts into strings:

```
result = [[word, str(count)] for (word, _), count in ordered]
```

I used `(word, _), count` as the `for` loop target, so Python unpacks the nested tuple structure for me and we can ignore the index. Because we don't use the index value in the output, I used the variable name `_`. Most code linters recognize this as *this value is not used*.

So a complete implementation would be:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

def word_count_engine(document):
    word_order = defaultdict(count().__next__)
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    cleaned = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]+", "", document.lower())
    for word in cleaned.split():
        counts[(word, word_order[word])] += 1

    # each sort item is a ((word, index), count) tuple, sort by descending counts
    # and then by ascending index.
    ordered = sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda kv: (-kv[1], kv[0][1]))

    return [[word, str(count)] for (word, _), count in ordered]
```

Demo:

```
>>> example = "Practice makes perfect, you'll get perfecT by practice. just practice! just just just!!"
>>> word_count_engine(example)
[['just', '4'], ['practice', '3'], ['perfect', '2'], ['makes', '1'], ['youll', '1'], ['get', '1'], ['by', '1']]
```

In Python 3.6 the implementation of the `dict` type was updated to save memory, a change that also happened to *record insertion order*. This means that the order that keys appear in, say, a `Counter()` produced from your words, would give you the words in document order *already*! In Python 3.7 this property became part of the language specification.

That's not to say that you can count on something like [`Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) to make use of this property! The documentation for that method is very clear on this:

> Elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily

However, *in practice* `Counter` is a straight-up subclass of `dict`, and as long as you don't pass in a value for the `n` argument to `Counter.most_common()` (or pass in a value less than the `Counter` length) a straight up `sorted()` call is used to produce the output and so you can also get the correct output using `Counter()`. **This is not guaranteed to continue to work in future Python versions**:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def word_count_engine(document):
    cleaned = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]+", "", document.lower())
    counts = Counter(cleaned.split())
    return [[word, str(count)] for word, count in counts.most_common()]
```

Comment: Thank you so much on the very informative answer works fine on python 3.6 (but not on pramp platform) which is fine, the only issue is that in the word "you'll" it should be counted as "youll" without the apostrophe but instead its divided into 2 word "you" and "ll"

Comment: @ElenaGT: ah, indeed, I'll fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much @Martijn, an article about you just popped on "Google Discover" while scrolling on my cell phone, you did pretty cool stuff, thanks for taking from your time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your tuples to lists and sort by the order in which the words appeared in the document if the counts are the same, you can sort by the count in reverse and then sort by the index of the word in a list created by splitting the input string after removing punctuation and lowercasing. Note that this approach will sort words with the same count in the order in which they first appear in the document (repetitions of the same word won't impact the sort).

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

s = "Practice makes perfect, you'll get perfecT by practice. just practice! just just just!!"

s = s.translate(s.maketrans('', '', punctuation))
s = s.lower()
words = s.split()
counts = sorted([list(t) for t in Counter(words).items()], key=lambda x: (-x[1], words.index(x[0])))
print(counts)
# [['just', 4], ['practice', 3], ['perfect', 2], ['makes', 1], ['youll', 1], ['get', 1], ['by', 1]]
```

Comment: the thing is I want to sort the words according to their order of appearance in the document if they have the same count

Comment: @ElenaGT - I see... answer edited accordingly. You may want to edit your question to clarify that you want to sort words with the same count "according to their order of appearance in the document" as noted in your comment.

Comment: @benvc: indeed, I had missed that it was *sentence order* that was needed.

Comment: @benvc sadly this won't work for cases like "you'll" because it will search for "youll" without the apostrophe and it won't find it in the list so it will return an error

Comment: @ElenaGT - sorry, should have been more clear that the list was created from the lowercase string where punctuation was already removed. Edited answer to make the example complete in case anyone runs across this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Improved and shortened (relying on [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object functionality):

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def word_count_engine(doc):
    doc = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]+', '', doc)  # remove all chars except words and whitespaces
    word_stats = Counter(doc.lower().split())
    return [list(t) for t in word_stats.most_common()]

input_doc = "Practice makes perfect, you'll get perfecT by practice. just practice! just just just!!"
print(word_count_engine(input_doc))
```

The output:

```
[['just', 4], ['practice', 3], ['perfect', 2], ['makes', 1], ['youll', 1], ['get', 1], ['by', 1]]
```

Comment: This only produces the correct order in Python 3.6 and up (and if not CPython, only if the alternative implementation adheres to the 3.7 spec *and* interprets Counter as being a strict subclass of `dict` with the same insertion order semantics.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I wondered about that. The most current docs for `Counter.most_common()` say _Elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily_.

Comment: Exactly, it is up to the implementation. For the case where `n` is not given, or `n >= len(counter)`, then `counter.most_common()` will use `sorted()` and the order happens to work. For smaller values of `n`, `heapq.nlargest()` is used, and the stability of the sort is gone.

Comment: Future Python versions could choose to use a different implementation and just dispense with sort stability altogether, however.